# Compiled c scripts only staying open for a fraction of a second

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, command-line

Beginner hobby programmer here. I'm used to running C in OSX compiling with GCC but I recently had to switch to windows. I'm compiling my code using Microsoft visual studio express 2010. The compiling goes fine but after that when I try to run it it only flashes open for a millisecond and then closes. How do I fix this?

This happens to all of the scripts I have tried but here is one in particular, the classic Fahrenheit and Celsius converter from K&R, that does not work. 
If this is a stupid question, sorry. Just started learning C two weeks ago.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    main()
   {
     int fahr, celsius;
     int lower, upper, step;
     lower = 0;     
     upper = 300;    
     step = 20;    
     fahr = lower;
     while (fahr <= upper) {
         celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
         printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
         fahr = fahr + step;
      }
   }
```

Comment: For reference, C programmers like to get offended when you call C code "scripts".  :)  Scripts run as is; C code almost always needs to be compiled first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put a `getch()` before your final brace `}`, this will require a keypress before the program exits

the only reason I suggest this rather than `ctrl-f5` is that it teaches you another C command :)

[edit]
Let me add a little more information to what you're doing.

The correct signature for main is `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, this is the value you should have in your program (to replace the single line `main()` that is currently there.

You don't have to do anything with those variables (argc & argv), they may be unused by you, the programmer.  However, the presence of the preceding `int` on the function name (main) means that it is expected to return a value.  Again, you probably don't care.  However, in the future, you or someone who is responsible for your code, will care.  What this means is that your `main` function should return some value, something to indicate it's success or failure to the underlying operating system (also, something to be used should you employ your programs in a shell script).

For the time being, a simple `return(0)`, after the aforementioned `getch()` will do the job nicely. 
[/edit]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to run the program under the debugger with <kbd>F5</kbd>.  Upon successful completion the debugger will immediately exit.  Try running outside the debugger and it will pause for a key press after completion: <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>

Note: The terminology script is not really accurate for C.  C is a compiled language and hence generally referred to as programs vs. a script.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it and using cool tags I've never seen ;-)

Comment: ah, thanks. As far as script goes I'm a python guy so that's sorta what I'm used to.

Answer (score 1):

The program you quote converts a range of fahrenheit temperatures to celsius, prints the results, and exits immediately. That's simply what the source code says: there is nothing in it to make it stay open.

If you compile and run in a Unix environment, you're most likely running it from a shell, inside a (virtual) terminal, and when the program finishes, the shell gives you a new prompt, but leaves the program's output visible above it. On Windows, however, the standard way to launch a program does not involve a shell or terminal window, so the program just writes its output somewhere you can't see and exits (or it opens a terminal window, but closes it right after it finishes running).

To see the output in Windows, you can open a terminal window yourself (run cmd.exe) and start the program from there, or you can add a `getch()` call at the end to make the program wait for a keypress before it exits.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the executable directly from a command line rather than from within the IDE, or call for some input at the end of main() to keep the window open.